# Rails 3 - Delete Multiple Records Using Checkboxes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

How do you delete multiple records using checkboxes in Rails 3?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

routes.rb:

```
  resources :blog_posts do
    collection do
      delete 'destroy_multiple'
    end
  end
```

index.html.erb:

```
<%= form_tag destroy_multiple_blog_posts_path, method: :delete do %>
<table>
...
<td><%= check_box_tag "blog_posts[]", blog_post.id %></td>
...
</table>
<%= submit_tag "Delete selected" %>
<% end %>
```

blog_posts_controller.rb:

```
def destroy_multiple

  BlogPost.destroy(params[:blog_posts])

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to blog_posts_path }
    format.json { head :no_content }
  end

end
```

Comment: If BlogPost belonged to a Collection, how would this work? Example: /collection/1/blogpost/1

Comment: Thanks. Using Rails 4, I had to put splat before params, like `*params[:blog_posts]`, otherwise it'd throw an error: `ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch: BlogPost(#-580055888) expected, got String(#-603015658)`

Comment: This is a really great answer. Do you know how I could add validation to ensure a user has selected a checkbox when they click the delete button?

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you want to display a list of records in a table, each with a check box,  and have a delete button that will cause all checked records to be deleted.

First,  you have to create names for the checkboxes that contain the record id,  you could do this:

```
<%= check_box_tag("delete[#{@thing.id}]",1) %>
```

That will create HTML that will include the following

```
 <input id='delete[1000]' type='checkbox' value='1' name='delete[1000]'>
```

So when you post a form, if you've checked the box for the records with id's 1001 and 1002, your post will contain:

```
"delete[1001]"=>"1"
"delete[1002]"=>"1"
```

So inside your controller,  you could do this

```
params[:delete].each do |id|
  Thing.find(id.to_i).destroy
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Send the ids of all checked elements on controller. I am assuming u have send ids to be deleted for Foo class to be deleted

```
ids = params[:ids]
Foo.where("id in (#{ids}")).destroy
```

or

```
ids = params[:ids].split(",")
Foo.where(id => ids).destroy
```

Use destroy, don't use delete if you have any dependencies.

Comment: `.where(:id => (params[:blog_posts])).destroy` would give me `ArgumentError in BlogPostController#destroy_multiple \ wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)`.