# Not able to multi delete, Is this correct syntax in routes.rb for collection?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to multi delete, have set all the correct code in controller and in views but it is not working. I have this code in my routes file, is this correct ? as I think the problem is here only

routes.rb file

```
  resources :profiles do
    collection { post :import }
    collection do 
      delete 'destroy_multiple'
    end
  end
```

in profile_controller.rb file

```
  def destroy_multiple
    Profile.destroy(params[:profiles])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to profiles_path }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
```

in index.html.erb file, in table I have

```
<td><%= check_box_tag "profiles[]", profile.id %></td>
```

and below table I have

```
<%= submit_tag "Delete selected" %>
```

**but when I click on this Delete selected button, nothing happens.**

**EDIT** - I have taken this multi delete code from here [Rails 3 - Delete Multiple Records Using Checkboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12711178/rails-3-delete-multiple-records-using-checkboxes)

**EDIT 2** - I had forgot to add

```
<%= form_tag destroy_multiple_profiles_path, method: :delete do %>
  ...
<%= end %>
```

which I have now added, still the button is not deleting the records and nothing is happening

Comment: What do you mean by "not working?" Be specific. What does the `form_for` look like?

Comment: @ChrisPeters - Chris, I edited the last part of question, when I click on this Delete selected button, nothing happens.

Comment: Hope you don't find my questions annoying... What does "nothing happens" mean? The browser sits there and processes no request? The screen is reloaded with no changes to the data?

Comment: @ChrisPeters - sorry just saw the comment, nothing happens means when I click on the button, the record doesn't get deleted and the page doesn't get loaded. So it is like clicking on non functioning button

Comment: Hmm, frustrating. You're sure the `check_box_tag`s and `submit_tag` are all within the `form_tag`? Do you get any errors in the Chrome console? Does anything happen particularly in the Network tab within the Chrome console?

Answer (score 1):

You've shown in your question that you're using `submit_tag` which would mean that you have a form.  Your form should set the method to `delete` and the action to the `destroy_multiple` path in order to get routed to the correct action.  In code that would be something like

```
= form_tag '/profiles/destroy_multiple', method: :delete do
```

Comment: Thanks, I had forgot to add the form_tag, now I have added (see the edit in question), still that button is not deleting selected records. Nothing happens when I click on it

Comment: can you paste the request you get when you click on that button?

Comment: how to find that ? on Chrome console, I am not seeing anything when I click on that button

Comment: in the development log. it should be in `Rails root/logs/development.log`