# Disable submit button of form_tag, if no check box is enabled

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox, submit-button

I am using the form_tag to delete multiple records at a time, same as described here : [Rails 3 - Delete Multiple Records Using Checkboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12711178/rails-3-delete-multiple-records-using-checkboxes).
I want to disable the submit button if no checkbox is checked and enable it as soon we check any of these button.
Tried multiple solution, but not worked

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I tried writing jquery function in js.coffee file in rails but not able to access the checkbox_id to check 'enabled' or not. I am new at jquery as well ruby and facing the problem. Please help!