# Ruby on Rails Form not calling the correct action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to implement deletion of multiple records using checkboxes, I'm trying to follow the answers from this post here.

[Rails 3 - Delete Multiple Records Using Checkboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12711178/rails-3-delete-multiple-records-using-checkboxes)

For whatever reason, my form is not calling the correct action from my controller even though my routes file and path specified look correct. From the log files on my server, it seems to be trying to perform the update action. I'll attach my code below and the error. Any help is greatly appreciated as I've spent hours trying to fix this.

routes.rb

```
resources :remove_matches do
    collection do
      delete :delete_selected
    end
  end
```

new.html.erb - The corresponding checkboxes are rendered in the partial in the tbody tag

```
<%= form_tag delete_selected_remove_matches_path, method: :delete do |f| %>

<div class='container-fluid'>
    <p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>
    <div class='row'>
        <div class='col-lg-12'>
            <h3 class=''>Matches</h3>
            <table class="table table-hover table-striped">
                <thead class="thead-inverse">
                    <tr>
                        <th rowspan="2">Match DateTime</th>
                        <th rowspan="2">Team 1</th>
                        <th rowspan="2">Team 2</th>
                        <th colspan="3">AsianHandicap Bet</th>
                        <th colspan="3">Over/Under Bet</th>
                        <th colspan="2">Matchline Bet</th>
                        <%= link_to "Delete All", clear_remove_matches_path, class: 
                    "btn btn-danger navbar-btn", data: {confirm: "Delete all match records?"}%>

                        <%= submit_tag "Delete Checked Records" %>
                        
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Team 1</th>
                        <th>AH</th>
                        <th>Team 2</th>
                        <th>OU</th>
                        <th>Team 1</th>
                        <th>Team 2</th>
                        <th>Team 1</th>
                        <th>Team 2</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                
                <tbody id="match-body">
                    <%= render 'remove_match_table.html.erb' %>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <br>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<% end %>
```

which renders the form...

```
<form action="/matches/delete_selected" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">

  <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓">

  <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="patch">

  <input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="7zxGfF9A6BkpzXQCK3QnTZd//Glja/c8XqINa3JWxZG84D8iM+X0qvCXd+77O7oaPbYP9yJJliQ2t7vgr7ALew==">

  <div class="container-fluid">...</div> 

</form>
```

Error from my server

```
[2020-12-22T22:20:41.169325 #29140]  INFO -- : [ce4721a6-4b62-4209-b560-574c1674fd56] Started PATCH "/remove_matches/delete_selected" for 174.91.15.24 at 2020-12-22 22:20:41 +0000
F, [2020-12-22T22:20:41.170976 #29140] FATAL -- : [ce4721a6-4b62-4209-b560-574c1674fd56]
F, [2020-12-22T22:20:41.171046 #29140] FATAL -- : [ce4721a6-4b62-4209-b560-574c1674fd56] AbstractController::ActionNotFound (The action 'update' could not be found for RemoveMatchesController):
F, [2020-12-22T22:20:41.171070 #29140] FATAL -- : [ce4721a6-4b62-4209-b560-574c1674fd56]
F, [2020-12-22T22:20:41.171102 #29140] FATAL -- : [ce4721a6-4b62-4209-b560-574c1674fd56] actionpack (5.0.7.2) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
[ce4721a6-4b62-4209-b560-574c1674fd56] actionview (5.0.7.2) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
[ce4721a6-4b62-4209-b560-574c1674fd56] actionpack (5.0.7.2) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:190:in `dispatch'
[ce4721a6-4b62-4209-b560-574c1674fd56] actionpack (5.0.7.2) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:262:in `dispatch'
[ce4721a6-4b62-4209-b560-574c1674fd56] actionpack (5.0.7.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:50:in `dispatch'
[ce4721a6-4b62-4209-b560-574c1674fd56] actionpack (5.0.7.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:32:in `serve'
[ce4721a6-4b62-4209-b560-574c1674fd56] actionpack (5.0.7.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:39:in `block in serve'
[ce4721a6-4b62-4209-b560-574c1674fd56] actionpack (5.0.7.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:26:in `each'
[ce4721a6-4b62-4209-b560-574c1674fd56] actionpack (5.0.7.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:26:in `serve'
[ce4721a6-4b62-4209-b560-574c1674fd56] actionpack (5.0.7.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:727:in `call'
[ce4721a6-4b62-4209-b560-574c1674fd56] warden (1.2.8) lib/warden/manager.rb:36:in `block in call'
[ce4721a6-4b62-4209-b560-574c1674fd56] warden (1.2.8) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
[ce4721a6-4b62-4209-b560-574c1674fd56] warden (1.2.8) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
[ce4721a6-4b62-4209-b560-574c1674fd56] rack (2.0.7) lib/rack/etag.rb:25:in `call'
[ce4721a6-4b62-4209-b560-574c1674fd56] rack (2.0.7) lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:38:in `call'
[ce4721a6-4b62-4209-b560-574c1674fd56] rack (2.0.7) lib/rack/head.rb:12:in `call'
[ce4721a6-4b62-4209-b560-574c1674fd56] rack (2.0.7) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:232:in `context'
[ce4721a6-4b62-4209-b560-574c1674fd56] rack (2.0.7) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:226:in `call'
```

Comment: I just removed the link_to entirely because I wasn't going to use that in the future. Still getting the same error unfortunately

Comment: Oops, that was from trying to use form_for previously. I removed the |f| as well but still giving me the same error

Comment: What does the html for the rendered form tag look like?

Comment: <form action="/matches/delete_selected" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓"><input type="hidden" name="_method" value="patch"><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="7zxGfF9A6BkpzXQCK3QnTZd//Glja/c8XqINa3JWxZG84D8iM+X0qvCXd+77O7oaPbYP9yJJliQ2t7vgr7ALew==">

<div class="container-fluid">...</div> 
</form>

Comment: `input type="hidden" name="_method" value="patch"` is why the form is going to the update method.  Are you sure there is a `method: :delete` in the form_tag?

Comment: PS. Best to edit the question with updates.

Comment: Can you add in your `rake routes` output too, and sections from the "deleted" section of your controller, please?